# Is there an equivalent of os.Args() for functions?

Tags: go

To help debug GO programs, I want to write two generic functions that will be called on entry and exit, which will print the values of input and output parameters respectively:

```
printInputParameters(input ...interface{})
printOutputParameters(output ...interface{})
```

Is there an equivalent of `os.Args()` for functions? I looked at runtime package and didn't find such functions.

For example lets say I have two functions with different input parameters and output parameters

```
func f1(int i, float f) (e error) {
    ... some code here
}

func f2(s string, b []byte) (u uint64, e error) {
     .. some code here
}
```

I want to be able to do the following

```
func f1(int i, float f) (e error) {
     printInputparameters( ? )
     defer func() {
          printOutputParameters( ? )
     }()

     ... some code here
}

func f2(s string, b []byte) (u uint64, e error) {
     printInputparameters( ? )
     defer func() {
          printOutputParameters( ? )
     }()

     ... some code here
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this in Go since there is no way you can get the stack frame of the currently active function in the current goroutine. It is not impossible to do this as I'll show further below but the problem is that there is no public API to get this done reliably. That it can be done can be seen in the stack traces printed when a `panic` is raised: all values on the stack are dumped in that case.

Should you be interested in how the stack trace is actually generated then have a look at [`genstacktrace`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/f2e4c8b5fb3660d793b2c545ef207153db0a34b1/src/runtime/traceback.go#L120) in the runtime package.

As for a solution to your problem, you can the source code parsing route as [already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33003479/1643939). If you feel adventurous, you can parse the stack trace provided by [`runtime.Stack`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Stack). But beware, there are so many drawbacks that you will quickly realize that any solution is better than this one.

To parse the stack trace, just get the line of the previously called function (from the viewpoint of `printInputParameters`), get the name of that function and parse the parameter values according to the parameter types provided by reflection. Some examples of stack trace outputs of various function invocations:

```
main.Test1(0x2) // Test1(int64(2))
main.Test1(0xc820043ed5, 0x3, 0x3) // Test1([]byte{'A','B','C'})
main.Test1(0x513350, 0x4) // Test1("AAAA")
```

You can see that complex types (those which do not fit into a register) may use more than one 'parameter'. A string for example is a pointer to the data and the length. So you have to use the `unsafe` package to access these pointers and reflection to create values from this data.

If you want to try yourself, here's some example code:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "reflect"
    "runtime"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "unsafe"
)

// Parses the second call's parameters in a stack trace of the form:
//
// goroutine 1 [running]:
// main.printInputs(0x4c4c60, 0x539038)
//  /.../go/src/debug/main.go:16 +0xe0
// main.Test1(0x2)
//  /.../go/src/debug/main.go:23
//
func parseParams(st string) (string, []uintptr) {

    line := 1
    start, stop := 0, 0
    for i, c := range st {
        if c == '\n' {
            line++
        }
        if line == 4 && c == '\n' {
            start = i + 1
        }
        if line == 5 && c == '\n' {
            stop = i
        }
    }

    call := st[start:stop]
    fname := call[0:strings.IndexByte(call, '(')]
    param := call[strings.IndexByte(call, '(')+1 : strings.IndexByte(call, ')')]
    params := strings.Split(param, ", ")
    parsedParams := make([]uintptr, len(params))

    for i := range params {
        iv, err := strconv.ParseInt(params[i], 0, 64)

        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }

        parsedParams[i] = uintptr(iv)
    }

    return fname, parsedParams
}

func fromAddress(t reflect.Type, addr uintptr) reflect.Value {
    return reflect.NewAt(t, unsafe.Pointer(&addr)).Elem()
}

func printInputs(fn interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(fn)
    vt := v.Type()
    b := make([]byte, 500)

    if v.Kind() != reflect.Func {
        return
    }

    runtime.Stack(b, false)

    name, params := parseParams(string(b))
    pidx := 0

    fmt.Print(name + "(")
    for i := 0; i < vt.NumIn(); i++ {
        t := vt.In(i)
        switch t.Kind() {
        case reflect.Int64:
        case reflect.Int:
            // Just use the value from the stack
            fmt.Print(params[pidx], ",")
            pidx++
        case reflect.Float64:
            fmt.Print(math.Float64frombits(uint64(params[pidx])), ",")
            pidx++
        case reflect.Slice:
            // create []T pointing to slice content
            data := reflect.ArrayOf(int(params[pidx+2]), t.Elem())
            svp := reflect.NewAt(data, unsafe.Pointer(params[pidx]))
            fmt.Printf("%v,", svp.Elem())
            pidx += 3
        case reflect.String:
            sv := fromAddress(t, params[pidx])
            fmt.Printf("%v,", sv)
            pidx += 2
        case reflect.Map:
            // points to hmap struct
            mv := fromAddress(t,params[pidx])
            fmt.Printf("%v,", mv)
            pidx++
        } /* switch */
    }
    fmt.Println(")")
}
```

Test:

```
func Test1(in int, b []byte, in2 int, m string) {
    printInputs(Test1)
}

func main() {
    b := []byte{'A', 'B', 'C'}
    s := "AAAA"
    Test1(2, b, 9, s)
}
```

Output:

```
main.Test1(2,[65 66 67],9,"AAAA",)
```

A slightly advanced version of this can be found [on github](https://github.com/githubnemo/pdump):

```
go get github.com/githubnemo/pdump
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried this version and one on the github. It works fine except for the string arguments. 

Note: 
I had to upgrade my go to 1.5.1 from 1.4.2 because reflect.ArraOf() was not supported in go1.4.2

Comment: @JosephSwaminathan Please post an issue on github or fix it and open a pull request. Thanks.

Comment: Posted an issue. The code seems OK unable to find a fix so far.

Comment: @nimo  Opened a pull request

Answer (score 0):

To generically print your functions' arguments, you can do this:

```
func printInputParameters(input ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Printf("Args: %v", input)
}
```

`printInputParameters` is [a variadic function](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html), and `input` is of type `[]interface{}`.

Comment: @RhytmicFistman Thanks. But I don't want to redefine the function definition. I just want be able to debug. (I edited my question to clarify)

Comment: Sorry, there's reflection, but I can only see the types of the arguments, not their values. You also need to specify the function's name...